# Как выйти на ring-0 в Windows

Tags: python, python-2.x

Могу ли я как-то выйти на ring-0 в Windows средствами python, и к примеру, завершить процесс?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Единственный способ получить привилегии нулевого кольца - это написать драйвер режима ядра. На Python это невозможно.

Comment: А на каких язык это можно сделать? Есть ли мануалы?

Comment: На Ассемблере, C или C++. Есть документация Windows SDK, но она не для слабых духом. Есть учебники по системному программированию под Windows. Сразу замечу, что среди них нет ни одного меньше 800 страниц и они тоже далеко не простые. Ну, и можно попробовать погуглить статейки, но учитывайте, что цена ошибки в этой области высока. Там где Python просто выплюнет ошибку, драйвер может убить вам систему.